# Append multiple attribute values inside csv

Tags: ruby, json, csv, hash, grep

I have stored the data in the following JSON/XML. Please find below link. I am looking to store the values of `des_facet`, `org_facet`, `per_facet`, `geo_facet` in my CSV in array. At the moment the values stored in my hash map stores these values in a separate column.

```
hash = article.attributes.select {|k,v| !["author","images","guid","link"].include?(k) }
hash_new = []
hash.values.map do |v|
    hash_new.push("\""+v.to_s+"\"")
end
hash_new.map(&:to_s).join(", ")
```

**Sample JSON:**

```
{
    "articles": [{
        "results": [{
            "title": "Ad Blockers and the Nuisance at the Heart of the Modern Web",
            "summary": "The adoption of ad-blocking technology is rising steeply. Some see an existential threat to online content as we know it, but others see a new business niche.",
            "source": "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/20/technology/personaltech/ad-blockers-and-the-nuisance-at-the-heart-of-the-modern-web.html",
            "date": "2015-08-20T00:00:00-5:00",
            "section": "Technology",
            "item_type": "Article",
            "updated_date": "2015-08-19T16:05:01-5:00",
            "created_date": "2015-08-19T05:00:06-5:00",
            "material_type_facet": "News",
            "abstract": "The adoption of ad-blocking technology is rising steeply. Some see an existential threat to online content as we know it, but others see a new business niche.",
            "byline": "By FARHAD MANJOO",
            "kicker": "",
            "des_facet": ["Online Advertising", "Computers and the Internet", "Data-Mining and Database Marketing", "Privacy", "Advertising and Marketing", "Mobile Applications"],
            "org_facet": ["Adblock Plus"],
            "per_facet": "",
            "geo_facet": ""
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want the respective CSV for the same format. Currently below is what I get.

```
"Ad Blockers and the Nuisance at the Heart of the Modern Web", "The adoption of ad-blocking technology is rising steeply. Some see an existential threat to online content as we know it, but others see a new business niche.", "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/20/technology/personaltech/ad-blockers-and-the-nuisance-at-the-heart-of-the-modern-web.html", "2015-08-20T00:00:00-5:00", "Technology", "Article", "2015-08-19T16:05:01-5:00", "2015-08-19T05:00:06-5:00", "News", "The adoption of ad-blocking technology is rising steeply. Some see an existential threat to online content as we know it, but others see a new business niche.", "By FARHAD MANJOO", "", "["Online Advertising", "Computers and the Internet", "Data-Mining and Database Marketing", "Privacy", "Advertising and Marketing", "Mobile Applications"]", "["Adblock Plus"]", "", ""
```

I am not sure how to do this. I am quite new to Ruby. I have thought of using grep probably and look out for value with `/[\]]/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to avoid writing CSV yourself, Ruby has a [`CSV`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/CSV.html) class included that does all escaping for you.

```
  unwanted_attributes  = ["author", "images", "guid", "link"]
  sanitized_attributes = article.attributes.select { |attribute_name, _| 
    !unwanted_attributes.include?(attribute_name) 
  }

  csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << sanitized_attributes.values
  end
```

Comment: I a trying to do this without a gem. If it is a default library, then it should be fine.

Comment: There are faster CSV gems out there, but this is a standard Ruby class.